# Apply color only to lower part of Chart.js line chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have this line chart[image: line chart]

How can i color the background only on the part of chart below the line? Like in this picture[image]

Here is the code that i'm using (this is part of a react component, as you can see from this.props):

```
    var canvas: any = document.getElementById('temperature-chart');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: this.props.labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Temperatures",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                data: this.props.numbers,
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
        },
```

I also customixed some options to remove the y axix and to add the labels.

Answer (score 4):

my solution -

```js
    datasets: [
        {
          fill:'start',
          backgroundColor: 'what you want',
          ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/area.html

Looks like your chart is filling to the origin, since you have negative and positive data this makes it fill above and below 0. Try adding:

```
fill: 1,
```

This should fill to dataset 1 and fill in the data you have.

Comment: I'e tried to use `fill: 1` but it removed the background.